# Linear inequalities question: $k+5 > 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

A text book that I'm reading has $k < -5$ as the solution for $k+5 > 0$. What I want to know is how this can be - why is it not $k > -5$?

Edit: looks like the text book's made a mistake.

Comment: Because they made a mistake?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm thinking as well. But I just need to make sure because it doesn't make logical sense. The book is http://www.amazon.co.uk/Mathematics-Higher-Level-Fabio-Cirrito/dp/1876659114/ref=pd_cp_b_0

Answer (score 3):

To get this question into the answered list:

The textbook made a mistake. Starting from
$$k+5>0$$
we can add $-5$ to both sides, producing
$$k+5+(-5)>0+(-5).$$
Because $5+(-5)=0$ and $0+(-5)=-5$, we have
$$k+0>-5.$$
Finally, because $k+0=k$, we have
$$k>-5.$$

Thus, the correct solution is $k>-5$, **not** $k<-5$.

Comment: Dear Zev: Thanks for all your editing work!!!

Comment: No problem! I am happy to help and it is excellent LaTeX practice :)